# 'document.createElement(...).constructor.prototype' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsf

I am new to JSF / programming. I have a simple jsf application which was working perfectly fine but all of a sudden my command buttons wont navigate to any page on one particular page. on that very page. i see a yellow exclamation mark on bottom left corner of IE. upon clicking, i get follow kind of error which i have no clue about:-

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;  
Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Wed, 18 Mar 2015 09:46:42 UTC

Message: 'document.createElement(...).constructor.prototype' is null or 
not an object

Line: 107442769
Char: 11390
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:8085/TESTAPP/pages/student/studentInfo.jsf
```

Please guide me where to start looking. I am jsf-naive so i dont know what all information do i have to share in question. Just give me a clue as to what could be the possible cause of such error. its greek to me.

Comment: looks like a feature test not working in IE8, and failing obtrusively. most likely the script is not compat with IE8; most good ones are not these days...

Comment: but the application is not working on firefox too (version 36.0.1)

Comment: well, you'll have to go to line # 107,442,769 and see. wait, are there really millions of lines? that many chars is too many, you must have something wacky going on...

Comment: thats the point. i dont have these much line numbers in the generated html atleast. is there any way to go to this line number other than F12 > Edit and then copying whole html pasting in word pad and searching for it?

Comment: in firefox you can usually click the error in firebug and ittl jump to it. you can also break on errors and land there.

Comment: ok let me chk it with fire bug. never used it but will google. thanks.

Comment: would you post the xhtml(JSF) structure of the page? the full structure please!